# How do I invoke a proc given the procedure name as a string?

Tags: reflection, nim-lang

Let´s assume we have the following procedure:

```
proc helloWorld() =
    echo "Hallo World"
```

Now, I want to invoke the procedure `helloWorld` given its name as a string.

```
let procName = "helloWorld"
invoke(procName)
```

Is this possible in Nim? In contrast to the Java Reflection API, can this be done at compile time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
import macros

proc helloWorld() =
  echo "Hallo World"

macro invoke(name: string): untyped =
  return newCall(name.strVal)

invoke("helloWorld")
```